# how to execute java -Xmx512m -jar a.jar yourfile.txt. command from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

1.>how to execute java -Xmx512m -jar a.jar yourfile.txt. from eclipse @junit

Answer (score 1):

You need to run it using the `java -jar` command. In order to do that :

Go to `Run`> `External Tools` > `External tools Configurations`

```
Create new item under "Program"
```

Fill followings .

```
Location: <JAVA_HOME>/bin/java 

Working directory: The working directory for your jar program (might be it's location)

Arguments: -Xmx512m -jar a.jar yourfile.txt.
```